Alpine Container: make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted
While running Alpine 3.20 container, make command complained about "Operation not permitted" while I have login as root.
Have been searching on the forums about the similar issue.
On RHEL7 environment with limited privileges to upgrade the versions of Docker alternative, Podman. Meanwhile, upgrading to Docker/Podman service is not an option for folks.
Looking for another option to change/update things in Alpine Container instead.

/tmp # docker-php-ext-install gd /bin/sh /usr/src/php/ext/gd/libtool
--tag=CC --mode=compile cc -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/webp -I/usr/include/freetype2  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE   -Wno-strict-prototypes -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd/libgd -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /usr/src/php/ext/gd/gd.c -o gd.lo  -MMD -MF gd.dep -MT gd.lo make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted make: ***
[Makefile:213: gd.lo] Error 127


Try using bmake instead of make, more stable than make in Alpine.

Don't know if that's okay to swap make as it's in core folder /usr/bin/.

The path to /ust/bin/make is just symbolic link to gmake. Remove the symbolic link and then create new link with make path as installed. Should do the work.

Can I try alias make="bmake" without removing symbolic link?

Assuming calling make command from external script/program, it’s versatile to change underlying path to ‘make’.

Can you suggest how to install bmake in Alpine environment?

Try “apk add —upgrade gcc libc-dev bmake”.

Great, seems to working as expected. Here's what I tried:
/tmp # apk add --upgrade gcc libc-dev bmake
/tmp # mv /usr/bin/make /usr/bin/make.bak
/tmp # ln -s /usr/bin/bmake /usr/bin/make

I have tried PHP extension installation command like /tmp # docker-php-ext-install gd which uses make to compile and now turned to use bamke behind the scene. Seems okay to be so far. Really appreciate!

Try
apk add —upgrade gcc libc-dev bmake

.
Replace /usr/bin/make with /usr/bin/bmake.

Just marked this as accepted answer. Many thanks!
